# AWS S3 CORS 403 Error with OPTIONS request

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access a html file which reside in the S3 from an ajax request and I got 403 error.

I read the AWS online that if I do such thing, I need to setup AWS CORS rules to fix the 403 error.

However, I have been trying two days and I don't have any luck. Here is my CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>XMLHttpRequest</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-csrftoken</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

And my HTTP request looks like:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-He...    x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
Origin  http://localhost:8000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
```

Can anyone help me to see what I have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out the problem is not S3 but cloudfront. Did anyone try to forward the CORS configuration from S3 to cloudfront?

Comment: This is such an infuriating thing to troubleshoot. It shouldn't be this difficult to configure an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5):

For those who came here for **403 on OPTIONS request of cross origin s3 access** and didn't find what they were looking for, perhaps my experience with this can help.

tldr; **browsers are designed to set the *origin* to *null* on 302 redirects from a different origin**

I also experienced a CORS issue on the preflight request to a resource on a bucket, a resource which was otherwise available if browsed to directly.

I had CORS configured on the bucket with the proper accepted headers and origin. Something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I then received an error along the lines of

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED]?AWSAccessKeyId=[REDACTED]' (redirected from '[REDACTED]') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

After inspecting the request headers, it was clear that the one suspect thing was the Origin having a value of "null".

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: null
Referer: [REDACTED]
User-Agent: [REDACTED]
```

As it turns out, **browsers are designed to set the *origin* to *null* on 302 redirects from a different origin** due to security issues. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv).

There is no fix to this issue other than to not do a redirect. *I had to redesign the backend resource that was doing a redirect to instead provide a link for direct access to the s3 bbject.*

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 (Frobidden) does not necessarily means that you need CORSs. One option is having all requests to cloudfront (same origin) and, in you distribution, several origins and behaviors. Ex:

```
Beavior   ->  Origin

/api/*    ->  my.api.com
/static/* ->  my.s3.bucket
```

But if you actually need cross-origin requests, The CORS headers should be forwarded by cloudfront and have the same behavior, in your example you probably want to be more permissive with the headers you allow (`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` ?). But that would be more related to the browser behavior than CLoudFront or S3.